# Can an Azure AD OAuth2.0 Access Token include custom data to identify the registered app to my API?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an Asp.Net Core 2.0 Web API running as a web app in Azure.  My API is consumed by client applications which are windows service running on servers at various client sites. So, this is a "Daemon or Server Application to Web API" communications flow as described in [Authentication Scenarios for Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#daemon-or-server-application-to-web-api)

I register the client application at each site as a separate unique app in Azure AD, obtain the  ClientId and AppKey and send it to the respective site for their devs to use in their service to request a JTW access token from Azure AD to use in the authorization header when making an http request to my API.

This is all working just fine.

The question I have is this; is there any way, in this scenario, that I can identify which site is making the request? From what I understand, it doesn't seem like I can add custom claims to an OAuth2.0 access token, like can be added to an OIDC ID token.

Answer (score 0):

If you register the apps yourself then you know all the client ids for each different site so your API could use the `appid` in the JWT access token (which is the client id) and cross reference it against a list of sites. Here is an example of a JWT token obtained using the client credentials grant type:

[image]

Comment: That looks like it would work. You wouldn't happen a code example of how to decode the access token within my API do you? Right now I am just using the [Authorize] attribute on my controllers and services.AddAuthentication( ..).AddAzureBearer(...); in startup.cs, so I am not really seeing the access token getting decoded.

Comment: I find examples for asp.net core 2.0 that show setting savetokens = true in ConfigureServices in Startup.cs but so far, the examples all refer to ... 

.AddOpenIdConnect(options => {
AuthenticationProperties
    options.SaveTokens = true; });

In my case,I am using the .AddAzureAdBearer(options => ...) and I do not find a SaveTokens property there.

Comment: I'm not sure you need to decode the token. Have a look at your ClaimsPrincipal as I would expect the middleware to populate the User Claims with the values from the token.